# Discord.js: [ object Object ]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I have been working on improving my ticket system and got into that problem:
[image: Problem]

My code is:

```
    await button.clicker.fetch();
    if (!button.clicker.member.roles.cache.has("859507507596230736")) return button.reply.send("Only staff can close the ticket.", true)
    var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Are you sure?")
    .setDescription("Are you sure you want to close this ticket?\nThis action cannot be undone.")
    .setFooter(button.guild.name)
    .setColor("RED")
    var bu1tton = new MessageButton()
      .setStyle(`red`)
      .setEmoji(``)
      .setLabel(`Proceed anyway`)
      .setID("sure")
    button.reply.send({ component: bu1tton, embed: embed }, true)
  }
```

After I changed `button.reply.send({ component: bu1tton, embed: embed }, true)` to `button.channel.send({ component: bu1tton, embed: embed })` it worked perfectly, although was viewable by everyone.

I understand the problem is `, true` but I don't understand why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[object Object]` is when you (or a component you're using) tries to concatenate an object with a string (or other output an object as string).  Unclear how that helps you.

Comment: Try using `button.reply.send({ component: bu1tton, embed: embed, ephemeral: true})`, maybe it will help you

Comment: I advise you upgrade to discord.js v13 so that you don't need any external packages for these things. It also will give you types, which makes it easier to see where you might have gone wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `ephemeral: true` instead of `}, true)`

Here is the code:

```js
button.reply.send({ component: bu1tton, embed: embed, ephemeral: true})
```